# cx-freeze does not include openpyxl and et_xmlfile

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I prepare the executable of one of my projects with cx_freeze.
During processing I don't see any errors but when I go to run the executable I have an error because `openpyxl` and `et_xmlfile` are missing. Both are present both in the project's venv and in python3.10's site_packages
My setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {"include_files": [("images", "images")]}
base=None

setup(
     name="its mine",
     version="0.1",
     description="Maybe last rebuild",
     options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
     executables=[Executable("index.py", base=base)],
)
```